# CMU Sphinx: property:'location' - Can't locate resource

Tags: java, cmusphinx

I am implementing [sphinx-4](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4) tutorial. But when run this tutorial I got

```
Exception in thread "main" Property exception component:'acousticModelLoader' property:'location' - Can't locate resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us
edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.InternalConfigurationException: Can't locate resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us
```

This is code I am using

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
        configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict");
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin");
```

I have also add both to `pom.xml` and also add `repositories` to `pom.xml`, as mentioned in tutorial.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>edu.cmu.sphinx</groupId>
            <artifactId>sphinx4-core</artifactId>
            <version>5prealpha-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.cmu.sphinx</groupId>
            <artifactId>sphinx4-data</artifactId>
            <version>5prealpha-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

What I am doing wrong? I am using windows 10 OS. Comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700836/cmu-sphinx-set-acoustic-model-path-error) question told something about classpath But it is not clear.

Comment: The solution is the same as in previous question: The error is due to the fact you didn't add sphinx4-data jar into your application classpath. In order to get help on this issue you need to explain how exactly do you add jars into classpath and how do you run your project.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I am using maven to add dependencies. I am adding sphinx4-data in maven pom.xml. I was having problem in one computer. Now, I run on another computer with same tutorial, project is running fine.

Comment: I asked how do you start the software, now how you compile it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used same jre version, same eclipse version and same workspace(copy-paste) on five different computers. sphinx4 worked on four of them and didn't work on the other one. I had the same error:

> Can't locate resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us

I do not know why that is happenning. Four of the computers is working well with Maven. As a solution to save the day, I downloaded Acoustic Model and Dictionary for the other computer. Then, I gave the local paths.

```
static String DictionaryPath = "file:C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\MyProject\\cmudict\\cmudict.dict";
static String AcousticModelPath = "file:C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\MyProject\\acoustic model\\cmusphinx-en-us-8khz-5.2";
```

So, this is not an actual solution, also it is incompatible with the Maven logic but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Specified the path manually under ubuntu and it worked

```
String AcousticModelPath = "/home/eclipse-workspace/speech/sound/en-us";
String DictionaryPath = "/home/eclipse-workspace/speech/sound/cmudict-en-us.dict";
String languageModelPath="/home/eclipse-workspace/speech/sound/en-us.lm.bin";
```